# Play Scala Json Missing Property vs Null

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have a use case where I need to accept null values, but not missing properties. 
This is on Play Framework 2.1.3

For example:

```
case class Foo(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String])
```

This case class could be part of a larger case class

I would like to accept the following and generate the foo object:

```
{
   "foo" : {
        "a" : "blah",
        "b" : null,
        "c" : "blah"
    }
}
```

But not this:

```
{
   "foo" : {
        "a" : "blah",
        "c" : "blah"
    }
}
```

Currently I have the following to read the JSON into the case class:

```
val FooReader = (
    (__ \ "a").readNullable[Setting] and
    (__ \ "b").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "c").readNullable[String])(Foo)
```

How can I make FooReader generate JsError on missing property but allow null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like :

```
val FooReader = (
  (__ \ "a").readNullable[String] and
  (__ \ "b").read(Reads.optionNoError[String]) and
  (__ \ "c").readNullable[String]
)(Foo)
```

The 'Reads.optionNoError[String]' will produce a JsError if '(__ \ "b")' is missing.

You can actually do something like :

```
val FooReader = (
  (__ \ "a").read(Reads.optionNoError[String]) and
  (__ \ "b").read(Reads.optionNoError[String]) and
  (__ \ "c").read(Reads.optionNoError[String])
)(Foo)
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me with : 
`  val FooReader = (
    (__ \ "a").read(Reads.optionNoError[String]) and
    (__ \ "b").read(Reads.optionNoError[String]) and
    (__ \ "c").read(Reads.optionNoError[String])
  )(Foo)`

Comment: Yea, it works for me now :) I think it got confused when I try to build Foo inside the companion object Foo. It works when I set the apply explicitly

Comment: I have a use case where a json might not contain all fields present in the original object, and some string fields that can be `null` which should validate as well as set the original obejct's fields to null.

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do that.